# AngularJS change property value based on another array

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a json data structured as:

```
$scope.items = [{"Color" : "Red", "Size": "Small" }, { "Color" : "Orange" "Size": "Small"}, {"Color" : "Green" "Size": "Extra-Large"}];
```

then I have a properties json data:

```
$scope.properties = [{"PropertyName" : "Color", "FilteredAs" : "AllColors"}, {"PropertyName" : "Size", "FilteredAs" : "AllSizes"}]
```

I am doing a server-side filtering that's why there's a FilteredAs property in my properties json data. What I want to happen is:

If (items.key = properties.PropertyName) 
example: "Color" (which is the first property in the items array) == "PropertyName" : "Color"
then that corresponding object's FilteredAs property in the properties array is "FilteredAs" : "AllColors", AllColors will be changed to "Red".

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I have for now:

```
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (value, key) {
            for (var i = 0; i<= $scope.properties.length; i++) {

                if ($scope.properties[i].PropertyName == $scope.items[value]) {
                    $scope.properties[i].SearchText = $scope.items[key];
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you update your description for what you want to happen. I don't understand what you mean exactly :)

Comment: I already edited the description, materik

Comment: When calling the Web Service I created, I wanted to change the FilteredAs property of the propertyname color as Red

Comment: Ok, I'm still very confused with the text, what does `If (items.key = properties.PropertyName)` mean, what is items.key? What do you mean `"Color" == "PropertyName"`, the strings? and why should AllColors be "Red"? There are multiple colors in your items list and what does AllColors mean in this case?

Comment: Items (key, value). Keys are Color, Size and Values are Red, Small, etc.

In the items array, Color is a property while in the properties array, the Color is a value of the propertyname.

FilteredAs is a property that I send to the web service. I have a logic in the backend. But never mind it. All I want to achieve is set properties.FilteredAs to "Red".

Comment: Ok, i understand a bit better. But again, why Red, why not Orange?

Comment: It's a search item. Users can enter anything.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly as $scope.properties is an array you would need to `foreach` through the objects and identify the property that is for Color. Below should do what your looking for.

```
$scope.properties.forEach(function (property) {
    if (property.PropertyName === "Color") {
        property.FilteredAs = "Red" // Or whatever value or variable you have got back from webservice
    }
});
```

Hope I have understood correctly and that this helps.

EDIT: 
Because `$scope.items` is an array angular.forEach doesn't work that same way as it does for an object. You would need to change the code to be something like below.

```
angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
        for (var i = 0; i<= $scope.properties.length; i++) {

            if ($scope.properties[i].PropertyName == "Color") {
                $scope.properties[i].SearchText = item.Color;
            }
        }
```

With this though the value of `$scope.properties[i].SearchText` will always be the last Color in the `$scope.items` array. You might need to add some checked to ensure the right color is selected from the array with what your WebService says.

Comment: Edited my post :) The bottom part.

Comment: In this line, I want to access $scope.properties[i].PropertyName == "Color" as $scope.items[value]?

Comment: It's the property "Color" in the items that I am getting :D

Comment: Using $scope.items[value] isn't possible as when you use that way of looking values up in an array you can only use the key. So $scope.items[key] which if key was "Color" you would get Red back for the first item in $scope.items. Is value what you have from your web service?

Comment: Is there a way to iterate the keys and values in the controller?

Comment: You could once inside the first angular.forEach($scope.items, ...) call another with the item variable angular.forEach(item, function (value, key) { // Do something here }); That would iterate through them for you.